# Putting one column from a multi column query into a list

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, asp.net-core

I am trying to put the Column LANS from this multi column query into a list.
And the First and Last name into a separate list.
I just can't figure out how to make it work.

CODE:

```
//Resource
var ResourceFilter =  _context.INT_CertificationsXREF.Include(i => i.RIM_Resource)
    .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN == i.RIM_Resource.LAN)
    .Where(i => i.Approved == true)
    .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN != UserInformation.Globals.LANID)
    .Select( i => i.RIM_Resource.FirstName + i.RIM_Resource.LastName + i.RIM_Resource.LAN)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var ResourceFilterNames = ResourceFilter.RIM_Resource.Firstname + RIM_Resource.LastName.ToList();

var ResourceFilterLANS = ResourceFilter.RIM_Resource.LAN.ToList();
```

Desired OutPut

ResourceFilterNames = Firstname" "Lastname, Firstname" "Lastname, ect....

ResourceFilterLANS = NQ90, RE97, I3R9, ect.

The list also need to be in sync order wise.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: Updated........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question...i think what you want is:

```
var ResourceFilter =  _context.INT_CertificationsXREF.Include(i => i.RIM_Resource)
    .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN == i.RIM_Resource.LAN)
    .Where(i => i.Approved == true)
    .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN != UserInformation.Globals.LANID)
    .Select( i => new {
               fullName = i.RIM_Resource.FirstName + " " + i.RIM_Resource.LastName,
               Lan = i.RIM_Resource.LAN
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

the you can retrieve the list of "fullNames" and "LANS" like this

```
List<string> fullNames = ResourceFilter.Select(x => x.fullName).ToList();
List<string> LANS = ResourceFilter.Select(x => x.Lan).ToList();
```

hope it helps

Comment: YOUR A SAINT. <3

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output I think this solution will work for you

```
var ResourceFilterNames= string.Join(",", ResourceFilter.Select(x => ( x.Firstname 
 + " " + x.LastName )));
var ResourceFilterLANS =  string.Join(",", ResourceFilter.Select(x=> x.Lan));
```

In order this solution to work you should delete `Select` from `ResourceFilter` or rewrite it like below:

```
 .Select( i => new { i.RIM_Resource.FirstName, i.RIM_Resource.LastName, i.RIM_Resource.LAN})
```

Comment: this won't work if he did't change his `select` statement...he is concatenating the values instead of select them...

Comment: @ElmerDantas Yes, I missed that. Thank you for you remark.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the following class as my test input:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Lan { get; set; }
}
```

My first solution assumes that your combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` is unique.

To hold your two lists in sync I will use a dictionary:

```
// var resource = new List<MyData>();
var dictionary = resource.ToDictionary(r => r.FirstName + r.LastName, r => r.Lan);
```

My second solution assumes that they are not unique so you can use this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach(var res in resource)
{
    var key = res.FirstName + res.LastName;

    List<string> value;
    if ( dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value.Add(res.Lan);
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary[key] = new List<string> {res.Lan};
    }
}
```